# C# Why is my calculations not adding correctly?

Tags: c#, datetime, while-loop

I am making a form that calculates reservation dates. 
On Fridays and Saturdays the charge for a room is $150 while on the rest of the days the charge is $120. I have used a while loop in order to set this up but for some reason it keeps calculating the wrong prices.

What it should look like:

[image]

What it looks like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
int nights = 0;
int price = 0;

private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime arrivalDate = DateTime.Parse(txtArrivalDate.Text);
        DateTime departureDate = DateTime.Parse(txtDepartureDate.Text);
        TimeSpan ts = departureDate.Subtract(arrivalDate);
        nights = ts.Days;

        while (arrivalDate != departureDate)
        {
            DayOfWeek dow = arrivalDate.DayOfWeek;
            if (dow == DayOfWeek.Friday || 
                dow == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                price = 150;
            }
            else
            {
                price = 120;
            }

            arrivalDate = arrivalDate.AddDays(1);

        }

        txtNights.Text = nights.ToString();
        int totalPrice = price * nights;
        txtTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString();
        int average = totalPrice / nights;
        txtAvgPrice.Text = average.ToString();
        txtArrivalDate.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: You're just setting `price` to a value then multiplying by the number of days.  You should instead add up the total price for each day by doing `totalPrice += 150;` and `totalPrice += 120;` in the loop.

Comment: You need to increment the price for each day ! In your case price is not updating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, `int totalPrice = price * nights;` this line should be removed, and in the while loop, `price += 120` or `price += 150` in each condition. `totalPrice` can simply be replaced by `price`.

You're not using the `price` set in while loop. `price` is set to 120 or 150 but then overwritten by the next value (previous value is completely ignored). So once your code gets out of the while loop, the latest `price` set is used and multiplied by total nights.

So what your code is doing is taking the `price` of the last day (2/1/2016 in this case) and multiplying it by total nights. What it should be doing is keeping a running total of `price` inside the loop.

Comment: Using `.Days` will still produce wrong results. `.TotalDays` should be used

Answer (score -3):

You're not doing anything with the `price`.

It should be used in the while loop.

Also, you should be using `.TotalDays`, not `.Days`.

Something like:

```
            public static (decimal price, int nights) GetPrice
        (DateTime arrivalDate, DateTime departureDate)
    {
        //This code assumes there is no time component in the dates provided 

        if(departureDate < arrivalDate )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Arrival after Departure");
        }

        if (departureDate.Date == arrivalDate.Date)
        {
            //TODO
            return (0, 0);
        }

        Decimal totalPrice = 0;
        DateTime day = arrivalDate;
        while (day != departureDate)
        {
            totalPrice += GetRate(day.DayOfWeek);
            day = day.AddDays(1);
        }
        return (totalPrice, (int)(departureDate - arrivalDate).TotalDays);
    }

    private static decimal GetRate(DayOfWeek dow)
    {
        return (dow == DayOfWeek.Friday || dow == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            ? 150
            : 120;
    }
```